# Why does it splice a lot of elements when it's supposed to take 2 away

Tags: javascript, arrays, p5.js

The goal is whenever your player goes on a cyan circle, it gets bigger and the circle goes, but instead now when you get a circle, a lot of the circles go (because I think too much data is being spliced). The whole thing with pull is something different, for a different feature I'm adding after I fix this problem. Right now, in the function checking whether you ate a circle or not, it returns the index value of which the Y+1(To avoid returning 0 somehow) position of the circle you ate. Then I get this value and splice it from the array of the x and y of all the circles. The big array containing all the circles coordinates is a 1d array to make it easier for me.

-This is based on an online game agar.io.

```
var playerX;
var playerY;
var playerSize = 10;
var playerSpeed = (playerSize / Math.pow(playerSize, 1.44)) * 20;
var Newcelltimer = 0;
var cell = []
var cellEaten = 0;
var eaten = false;
//var pull = 1;

function setup() {

  frameRate(50)
  createCanvas(600, 450);
  playerX = random(30, width - 30);
  playerY = random(30, height - 30);


}

function draw() {


  playerSpeed = (playerSize / Math.pow(playerSize, 1.44)) * 10


  Newcelltimer++;

  background(220);

  if (keyIsDown(UP_ARROW) && playerY - playerSize / 2 >= 0) {
    playerY -= playerSpeed;
  }
  if (keyIsDown(RIGHT_ARROW) && playerX + playerSize / 2 <= width) {
    playerX += playerSpeed;
  }
  if (keyIsDown(DOWN_ARROW) && playerY + playerSize / 2 <= height) {
    playerY += playerSpeed;
  }
  if (keyIsDown(LEFT_ARROW) && playerX - playerSize / 2 >= 0) {
    playerX -= playerSpeed;
  }

  if (Newcelltimer % 100 === 0) {
    cell.push(random(10, width - 10), random(10, height - 10))

  }

  for (var i = 0; i < cell.length / 2; i++) {

    fill(0, 255, 255, 100)
    circle(cell[i * 2], cell[i * 2 - 1], 7)
  }



  fill(255, 255, 0)
  circle(playerX, playerY, playerSize)
  fill(0)
  ellipse(playerX - playerSize / 5, playerY - playerSize / 10, playerSize / 5, playerSize / 3)
  ellipse(playerX + playerSize / 5, playerY - playerSize / 10, playerSize / 5, playerSize / 3)
  arc(playerX, playerY + playerSize / 5, playerSize / 2, playerSize / 5, 0, 3.2, PIE)
  fill(255, 255, 0)
  noStroke()
  arc(playerX, (playerY + playerSize / 5) - 1, playerSize / 2, playerSize / 5, 0, 3.2, PIE)
  stroke(0)

  var Xindices = [...cell.keys()].filter(i => cell[i] >= playerX /*-pull*/ - playerSize / 2 && cell[i] <= playerX /*pull*/ + playerSize / 2);

  var Yindices = [...cell.keys()].filter(i => cell[i] >= playerY /**-pull*/ - (playerSize / 2) && cell[i] <= playerY /*+pull*/ + (playerSize / 2));

  function eatCheck(arr1, arr2) {

    for (let i = 0; i < arr1.length; i++) {
      for (let j = 0; j < arr2.length; j++) {
        if (Math.abs(Xindices[i] - Yindices[j]) === 1) {
          return j+1;
        }
      }


    }
    return false;
  }







  for (var j = 0; j < Yindices.length; j++) {
    if (Yindices[j] % 2 === 0 | Yindices[j] == 0) {
      Yindices.splice(j, 1)
    }
  }


  for (var j = 0; j < Xindices.length; j++) {
    if (Xindices[j] % 2 === 1) {
      Xindices.splice(j, 1)
    }
  }

  
  if (eatCheck(Xindices,Yindices)!=false)
    {
    playerSize += 7;
    cell.splice(Xindices[j-2])
    cell.splice(Yindices[j-1])
    cellEaten++;}
  if (playerSize >= width | playerSize >= height) {
    if (width > height) {
      playerSize = height;
    } else {
      playerSize = width;
    }




  }
  if (Newcelltimer % 500 === 0) {
    cell.splice(0, 2)
  }
  // if(pull>=75)
  //   {
  //     pull = 75;
  //   }


  fill(0)
  text("Your Size is: " + playerSize, 30, 30)
  // text("Your pull is: "+pull,30,60)
  // text("Upgrade your pull for "+pull*5+" size",430,45)
  // fill(0,0,0,0)
  // rect(410,20,187,50)


  // if(mouseClicked&&mouseX>410&&mouseX<600&&mouseY>20&&mouseY<50&&playerSize-10>pull*5)
  //   {
  //     playerSize-=pull*5
  //     pull++;
  //   }
}
```

Comment: You are looping over an element and removing indexes from it..... so when you yank the index out, the next one moves down and fills the spot. You then move to the next index in your loop. So you never look at the index that slides down. I would guess you are not removing enough....

Comment: Is there a simple solution to this? Also, I don't think the whole array  should be empty for this reason when 2 values are supposed to be spliced,

Comment: You are also using a bitwise or `|` did you really mean to use that and not `||`

Comment: Typically you loop backwards when removing indexes from an array.

Comment: Yes, if you use || it doesn't work anymore.

Answer (score 1):

The specific issue with the sketch that causes all cyan circles to be removed when the player's circle moves over one of them is here:

```
if (eatCheck(Xindices,Yindices)!=false)
{
  playerSize += 7;
  cell.splice(Xindices[j-2])
  cell.splice(Yindices[j-1])
  cellEaten++;
}
```

The call to `splice` needs to specify how many to remove. This code change will cause the one circle that is being eaten to be removed:

```
if (eatCheck(Xindices,Yindices)!=false)
{
  playerSize += 7;
  cell.splice(Xindices[j-2],1); // remove 1 item from the list
  cell.splice(Yindices[j-1],1); // remove 1 item from the list
  cellEaten++;
}
```

Here is some info on [splice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice)

> If deleteCount is omitted, or if its value is equal to or larger than array.length - start (that is, if it is equal to or greater than the number of elements left in the array, starting at start), then all the elements from start to the end of the array will be deleted.